# Why does abs(1.5) return 0, not 1 or 2 on ideone.com?

Tags: c

I tried the following test on ideone.com

(NOTE: My local machine does NOT give this problem)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float f = abs( 2 );   printf( "%f \n", f ); // 2.000000
    float g = abs( 1.5 ); printf( "%f \n", g ); // 0.000000

    return 0;
}
```

The prototype for abs is 'int abs(int)'

Hence I would expect g to return 1 or 2; I would expect the '1.5' to be converted to an integer.

This can be demonstrated on ideone.com: http://ideone.com/reyITY

Can someone explain this behaviour?

PS  I know I should be using fabs (or fabsf?) but nevertheless I would like to understand why this breaks in the way it does

Comment: `float f = abs( 2.0f );` also returns `0.0000`, so I guess that compiler just doesn't like to do that conversion

Comment: @Pi Probably your complier somehow and somewhy includes `stdlib.h` upon including `stdio.h`, while theirs doesn't. So better do it right and include what you need. See [this example](http://ideone.com/X3V7cf) as well.

Comment: @glglgl apparently clang does ... which confused me at first, so for clang it is a conversion.

Comment: I am guessing this is Visual Studio? Since both `clang` and `gcc` should produce a warning regardless of flags on an implicit function declaration.

Answer (score 10):

You havn't included `<stdlib.h>` which declares `abs`.

This means calling `abs( 1.5 );` , the compiler assumes there's a `int abs(double)` function somewhere, and it will generate code to call that.

The parameters will not match (int vs double), so you'll get undefined behavior.

Comment: But shouldn't it report an error, that it cannot find any 'int abs(double)' symbol?

Comment: @Pi No, C will accept that. A missing prototype is not an error, and only the symbol name matters, not its type/parameters when linking. (imo, always enable compiler flags that makes missing prototypes an error, or at the very least a warning)

Comment: @Pi `gcc` produces a warning for this regardless of the flags you use, unfortunately it seems like `clang` bring in `stdlib.h` with `stdio` but if you remove that then it also produces a warning, again regardless of the flags used. Visual Studio on the other hand does not produce an error.

Answer (score 6):

`abs` is declared in `stdlib.h`. Just include it.

Your compiler should have complained that `abs` was not declared. If not, add suitable flags or switches.